# Extracting equal rows of two data frames (in R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```
a1<-data.frame(a=c(0.5,0.4,0.4,0.2),b=c(0.4,0.3,0.5,0.2))
```

and

```
a2<-data.frame(Check1=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5),Check2=rep(c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),times=5),Result=letters[1:25])
```

a1 are a collection of observations of two values, so the different rows are sets of observations. We can look at data frame a2 to read what kind of result (third column of a2) we should expext for the observed combinations in a1. For example, first row in a1 is (0.5,0.4), and we see in a2 that this gives us result "x".

Now, I would like to create a new column in a1 with values from "result" column in a2, which matches the rows we find in a1. Such that, for example, the first row in a1.new becomes:
(0.5,0.4,"x")

The output would be:

```
a1.new<-data.frame(a=c(0.5,0.4,0.4,0.2),b=c(0.4,0.3,0.5,0.2),Result=c("x","r","t","g"))
```

Is there an effective way to do this?

Comment: corresponding results from a2 or a1 ? can you show output that you expect out of these data frames ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match the columns

```
a1$result <- a2$Result[match(paste0(a1$a,a1$b), paste0(a2$Check1,a2$Check2))]
```

The `match` returns the position of the first argument [ie. paste0(a1$a,a1$b)] in the second [ie. paste0(a2$Check1,a2$Check2)]. So this produces

```
(m <- match(paste0(a1$a,a1$b), paste0(a2$Check1,a2$Check2)))
#[1] 24 18 20  7
```

Then a2Result is subset using `[`. This selects the values of a2$Result at the corresponding positions produced by the match.

```
a2$Result[m]
#[1] "x" "r" "t" "g"
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort of like this:

```
newcol<-vector()
for (j in 1:nrow(a2) ) {
   thematch  <- which(a2[,1:2] == a1[j,])
   if (length(thematch)>0 ) newcol<-c(newcol,a2[thematch,3])
   }
```

Then, assuming every row in `a1` has a match,  `sa1.new <- cbind(a1,newcol)`

I think that'll do it.

Comment: Is it a parenthesis missing in 'which' line?

Adding the parenthesis and running your code gives me the following error:

Error in Ops.data.frame(a2[, 1:2], a2[j, ]) : 
  == only defined for equally-sized data frames

Comment: @ErosRam yep, sorry for misprints - see edits. But i think I like user20650's answer better in any case.